# Latest Docker update broken Heroku cli?

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

As the --email parameter is removed in docker login (version v17.06), I am unable to login with `heroku container:login`,
I get the following error:

`unknown flag: --email
See 'docker login --help'.
 !    Error: docker login exited with 125`

I am running latest heroku-cli version:
`heroku-cli/6.12.0-a504409 (darwin-x64) node-v7.10.0`

Any update coming to this, as now it seems I am unable to deploy any docker application to heroku?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `--email` attribute was used in an earlier version of Heroku's Docker tools. Check the output of `heroku plugins` and see if you have `heroku-container-tools` listed, if you do then perform `heroku plugins:uninstall heroku-container-tools` and then run `heroku plugins:install heroku-container-registry`.

Comment: Thanks John, reinstalling and installing heroku-container-tools helped. (btw you have a typo in last command, it should be `heroku plugins:install heroku-container-tools`

Comment: heroku-container-tools has been deprecated, (see https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-tools) - `heroku-container-registry` is the new one. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-tools/blob/master/commands/login.js#L36 is the cause of your original issue.